# How to pass Orbeon dropdown control selected value to script

Tags: xpath, orbeon

The following code works for radio buttons.

```
<xf:select1 id="User-Status-control" appearance="full" bind="User-Status-bind">     
   <xf:itemset ref="instance('User-status')/item">
      <xf:label ref="@value"/>
      <xf:value ref="@name"/>
   </xf:itemset>
   <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
      <xxf:script>
         var op1 =  ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(this);
         alert("op1 : " + op1);   // print the selected radio button ID.
      </xxf:script>
   </xf:action>
```

but it does not works for dropdown

```
<xf:select1 id="User-Status-control" bind="User-Status-bind" appearance="dropdown">
```

How can I get the value of an Orbeon *dropdown* control?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. You can use `ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue()` on a dropdown in the same way you can use it on radio buttons. Really, from that perspective, there should be no difference.

Comment: It could be that this is because the dropdown is now an XBL component, which doesn't export an external value.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<fr:dropdown>` AKA `<xf:select1 appearance="dropdown">` is a compound control, you have to go search for the nested `.xforms-select1` control. Something like:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(ORBEON.jQuery(this).find('.xforms-select1')[0])
```

I have updated the [doc](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html#for-compound-xbl-controls) to reflect this.